# Flutter IOS ) xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:

Tags: ios, flutter

Hello I am developing mobile application with Flutter.

I think After I update X Code 13.0 I am getting below error..

I am stuck on this for few weeks, I can run the app on Android and Web... But whenever I try to run on IOS.. I am keep getting this error.

I actually can not understand what exactly this error means..

I am waiting for you help.

Thanks for reading.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in tetbee...
Launching lib/main.dart on DAEGIL의 iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: T6ULPGT4J7
Xcode build done.                                            7.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-10-15 16:51:30.486 xcodebuild[53522:2541044]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-19114/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:373
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008020-0011243A2279002E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x139eb11b0>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x13a0f30d0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-001444810A31001E }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EDAD5055-209E-43BF-A48F-F0A2D8D26F43, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6D279D6B-91AD-43A0-ADEA-9C19BDE7F867, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CB7171EA-2225-4747-9F52-701A93AAEB11, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5142D23C-2C4B-4A12-B1D7-0F50CC53106F, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C74123E-BC00-4D28-B2F4-F76E0CACDF7C, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FB6CB2E0-F4D7-49C9-96F5-AD4A9C5D142F, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6B2EBF24-9E52-49C1-A11E-B41DFEF488B5, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7FBEFA6E-7F73-4EDD-9ED6-E3F4ADA07594, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5052D38E-6406-437B-8768-4D94AD187A7F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:02D10359-328E-4863-A07F-A5B2F3D128BE, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0DD09E94-836C-445C-80FF-E3638CE49F1A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DCFEC142-0FD1-4796-818F-A4FA4F1A2534, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8D4C4C17-B329-4FD3-B4F2-4A5A049B7C3F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:58970621-D588-4904-B2F5-79C74A9AFC2E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2C1D0A4C-95BE-4476-8135-5CA2AD5FF105, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6FC7662-3118-485F-A613-5BF9BF50C45A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:211B26BA-8FE6-44DB-9240-052F8679C4AD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6500BCAE-6A58-4C85-B929-5AA61506EF4B, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:31F77AF0-F029-450C-82DE-36EBEA06237C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:777A2E59-4F4C-4016-845B-B0942CD82224, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:986504B0-5A78-4148-8051-C0489CDAAB37, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
In file included from /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:5:
/Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
```

Comment: I got the same error, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: same here, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think´s a kind of a problem with Flutter on M1 Macs. Try please changing to the master channel as in Flutter Channel Master

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I'm on a 2019 pre-M1 mac so I don't think that's the issue.